# API Array [0] Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api

I am returning data from an api using the getJSON method. The api is from last.fm, and here is the code I have below...

```
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=ba2641c3bcc4d9e90ff25d4a7414f4ec&mbid='+lastresult1mbid+'&format=json', function (infodata) {
        console.log(infodata);       

         var lastrel1 =(JSON.stringify(infodata.album.releasedate));
         var releasedate1 = $.parseJSON(lastrel1);

         var fmtracks =(JSON.stringify(infodata.album.tracks.track[0].name));
         var tracks1 = $.parseJSON(fmtracks);

         $('#lastfminfo1').append(""+releasedate1+"");

          $('#tracks1').append(""+tracks1+"");

 });
```

For the varible fmtracks there are 15 tracks in this album I need to display, so how can I output them all to the `lastmininfo1` div?

`Track[0].name` will work, as will `track[1]`.

I need a loop or [i] or a each function to display them all but everything I am trying will not work.

Help or a point in the write direction would be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `lastresult1mbid`?

Comment: "everything I am trying" - show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=ba2641c3bcc4d9e90ff25d4a7414f4ec&mbid=d63d427d-499c-4eb4-996e-535e36013766&format=json', function (infodata){ 

        console.log(infodata);
        var trackList = infodata.album.tracks.track
        for(var i = 0, currentTrack; currentTrack = trackList[i]; ++i){
                $("#lastfminfo1").append(currentTrack.name);
            } 
    })
```

This works, you just need to loop through the tracks and append any information you want from them. This just does the name without any tags.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klatzkaj/3Z884/1/

Comment: And it avoids the senseless, redundant stringify/parseJSON code.

Comment: Just as a tip - `$.getJSON()` parses JSON automatically, so there's no need to use `parseJSON()` or `.stringify()` once you use the request, which I believe is what he was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you'll have to loop over them, or when supporting IE<9 isn't an issue you could use the [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on `tracks` and push each title to an array.

Since you're using jQuery, however, you may want to look into [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).